# Generating Different Number C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make simple two-player strategy game.

There are 3 posts which are constructed linearly.

There are 24 beads (12 white and 12 green).

Always the player with white color starts to play.

The first player to be able to place three bead of their color in a row, either vertically, horizontally or diagonally, wins the game.

Beginning with all of the posts empty, players take turns placing a bead of their color into any cell (randomly generated). In other words, DON’T TAKE ANY INPUT FROM THE USER, determine the cell randomly to place a bead.

If both players play all twenty-four beads without completing a string of three beads in a row or column or diagonal, the game is over without any winner (tie).

In your program, you should use one-dimensional array for each post.

The program should display all posts at each step until the game is over.

At the end of the game, the winner should be displayed, if exists.

```
    protected static int origRow;
    protected static int origCol;

    protected static void WriteAt(string s, int x, int y)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(origCol + x, origRow + y);
            Console.Write(s);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        origRow = Console.CursorTop;
        origCol = Console.CursorLeft;

        Random rnd = new Random();

        int a1 = 0, a2 = 0, b1 = 0, b2 = 0;

        List<int> horizontally = new List<int>();
        List<int> vertically = new List<int>();
        HashSet<int> repeathor = new HashSet<int>();
        HashSet<int> repetver = new HashSet<int>();

        Console.WriteLine(@"P1 | | | | | | | | |");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(@"P2 | | | | | | | | |");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(@"P3 | | | | | | | | |");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            a1 = 1; b1 = 1;
            while (a1 %2 != 0)
            {
                a1 = rnd.Next(4, 19);
            }
            while (b1 % 2 != 0)
            {
                b1 = rnd.Next(0, 5);
            }
            while (horizontally.Contains(a1) && vertically.Contains(b1))
            {
                a1 = 1; b1 = 1;
                while (a1 % 2 != 0)
                {
                    a1 = rnd.Next(4, 19);
                }
                while (b1 % 2 != 0)
                {
                    b1 = rnd.Next(0, 5);
                }
            }
            horizontally.Add(a1);
            vertically.Add(b1);
            WriteAt("W", a1, b1);
            a1 = 1; b1 = 1;
            while (a1 % 2 != 0)
            {
                a1 = rnd.Next(4, 19);
            }
            while (b1 % 2 != 0)
            {
                b1 = rnd.Next(0, 5);
            }
            while (horizontally.Contains(a1) && vertically.Contains(b1))
            {
                a1 = 1; b1 = 1;
                while (a1 % 2 != 0)
                {
                    a1 = rnd.Next(4, 19);
                }
                while (b1 % 2 != 0)
                {
                    b1 = rnd.Next(0, 5);
                }
            }
            WriteAt("G", a1, b1);

            horizontally.Add(a1);
            vertically.Add(b1);

            Console.ReadLine();  
        }




        Console.ReadLine();  

    }
```

I am trying to randomize different a1 and b1 numbers every for step. For example one time a1 = 5 , b1 = 7 then a1 and b1 cannot get this numbers at the same time again.

Comment: What went wrong and what is the correct behavior you expected instead?

Comment: Create a static table of numbers. Generate a random index to pull a number. If the number has been consumed take the nearest neighbor.

Comment: So are you trying to find a way to avoid choosing a location that has already been used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you're writing is basically Tic-Tac-Toe for larger boards.  Same rules, different board size.  You can find plenty of examples out there of how to write Tic-Tac-Toe as a beginner's exercise.  The code examples below make no assumptions about the size of the board so you can use any size you like.

Now, in order to ensure that you don't try to place a piece in the same location as another piece you need some way to record the current state of the board.  You will also need this for the code you will be writing to determine win conditions, since you will need to scan the board's state.

In order to do this you need to have three sets of information, one for each 'post' which you will record the placements in, so you need 3 collections, or perhaps a 2-dimensional array of an appropriate size.

```
// Declare an array with 3 rows, 8 columns - change size for different boards
int[,] board = new int[3,8];
```

This will be initialized to all 0s, so we can use 0 as the empty space.  If you prefer you can have the board be `char[,]` and use the characters that you will be using for the output image.  For now I will use 1 for white, 2 for green.

Printing the board in the format you're using:

```
public static void PrintBoard(int[,] board)
{
    Console.Clear();
    for (int row = 0; row < board.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        Console.Write("P{0} |", row);
        for (int col = 0; col < board.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            // Figure out what is at the current position
            int content = board[row,col];
            char c = content == 1 ? 'W' : content == 2 ? 'G' : ' ';
            Console.Write("{0}|", c);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Now when you want to check if a move is valid you can test the value at the location in the board:

```
public static bool IsMoveValid(int[,] board, int row, int col)
{
    if (row < 0 || row >= board.GetLength(0))
        return false;
    if (col < 0 || col >= board.GetLength(1))
        return false;
    return board[row,col] == 0;
}
```

The problem with this method is that as the board fills up you will get more and more rejections from the `IsMoveValid` method, until eventually you run out of places to put the next marker.

So the better method would be to generate the list of all empty spaces in the board and then choose randomly from that list.

For this I'll use a structure that holds a position on the board:

```
public struct Position
{
    public int Row;
    public int Column;
}
```

And now...

```
public static Position[] GetAvailableMoves(int[,] board)
{
    List<Position> results = new List<Position>();
    for (int row = 0; row < board.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < board.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            if (board[row,col] == 0)
                results.Add(new Position { Row = row, Column = col });
        }
    }
    return results.ToArray();
}
```

And to use that to generate a valid move:

```
Position[] availableMoves = GetAvailableMoves(board);
if (availableMoves.Length < 1)
{
    // no valid moves left, do something about end of game condition here
    return;
}

// choose one of the available moves
Position move = availableMoves.Length < 2 ? availableMoves[0] : availableMoves[rand.Next(0, availableMoves.Length)];

// put white token in position - change this for green's turn
board[availableMoves.Row, availableMoves.Column] = 1;
```

There are lots of ways of doing this, but hopefully this will give you some ideas.